# Akka Streams, Java and Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, akka

I have been wanting to work on getting Akka Streams (java) to work with Android Studio for a learning project. I add the Akka Actor and Akka Streams dependency to the build.gradle and it syncs perfectly well, adding both of those to the external files. The project bulids fine, but once deployed the app crashes with the following error

`Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.example.akkamagic-ln3G_VACZwI9pFOWqDOdPQ==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.example.akkamagic-ln3G_VACZwI9pFOWqDOdPQ==/base.apk': Bad index for method_handle_item method_idx: ffff >= f99b`

I've come across things that told me to insure that

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
```

That's added. I've set jetifier to false, since that created a different set of errors and I've added the following for file conflicts.

```
  packagingOptions {
            pickFirst 'google/protobuf/*'
            pickFirst 'google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto'
            pickFirst 'reference.conf'
        }
```

Here's the entire build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.akkamagic"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        packagingOptions {
            pickFirst 'google/protobuf/*'
            pickFirst 'google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto'
            pickFirst 'reference.conf'
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'io.magicthegathering:javasdk:0.0.16'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.6.3'
    implementation 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.6.3'
}
```

and the gradle.properties

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=false
```

At this point I don't have any actual code in the project that uses the akka library. If I remove the two akka dependencies from the build.gradle the project syncs, builds, deploys and runs as it should.

I am aware that Akka Streams probably isn't the best for the app I'm running, but I'm just trying to really learn how akka streams works and I don't want to have to learn HTML/CSS/JavaScript right now.